# Python String Length Two Values

Tags: python, string, string-length

I have the following code:

```
errors = the_data.loc[the_data['Column'].str.len() != 2 or 3]
```

Basically, I would like a row to be flagged when the column value is not 2 or 3 characters long. It works fine when I have it like this:

```
errors = the_data.loc[the_data['Column'].str.len() != 3]
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: There is no `.len()` method for strings, you either meant `str.__len__()` or `len(str)`. `len() != 2 or 3` is `( len()!=2 ) or (3)`, which is `( len()!=2 ) or (true)`, which is always true.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps the right way to go is

```
errors = the_data.loc[not (2 <= len(the_data['Column']) <= 3)]
```